# How to use relative path 'fetch' in NextJs App Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, app-router

I'm trying to fetch data using `fetch("/api/status")`, but it only finds URL when I use the absolute path: `fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/status")` .
Without using your path saved in a variable.

Comment: Are you using that `fetch` within the server scope (server component or SSR)? Because, if yes, you need the absolute path, because the server doesn't knoq whats the host.

Comment: @RobinThomas I'm using the server component, so there's currently no way to use a relative path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the `fetch` within a Next.js server component, `fetch` will not work without absolute url.

> However, constructing a request with new Request(url) or running fetch(url) when url is a relative URL does not work
>
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/middleware-relative-urls

So you have a few options to get it working:

1. Convert your server component to a client component. Relative urls will work fine in client component.
2. Save the host in a variable (or better an environment variable)
3. Use a third-party library like `axios` instead of `fetch`. With this, you can create a global instance just for your host.

```
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://localhost:3000`,
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  },
});
```

Then use `axiosInstance` instead of your `fetch` calls. You can then use relative urls here.